# Laravel bouncer performance for many models

Tags: laravel

I have many models (cca 200 customers) and I need to show to user only allowed customers rows like this:

```php
$customers = Customer::orderBy('name')->get()->filter(function ($customer) {
    return BouncerFacade::can('view', $customer);
});
```

This is slow. It is posible to extract allowed customers IDs and use them in query or load user abilities at onece at least?

Comment: What is the logic behind who can view each customer?

Comment: `->get()` receives all records. 200 records is a very small amount. So your bottleneck is probably looping over 200 records and letting the facade do a costly operation? Instead of a facade you could have permissions modeled in the database, which would make it one query and receiving a direct result.

Comment: Alternatively, you could cache the result? The first time it will be a bit slow but then it will be retrieved much faster.

Comment: The slow part is BouncerFacade::can('view', $customer);. I will try bypass complex bouncerl logic and ask database directly. Cache result is poslible solution but i do not know what all invalidate it. Thanks for hints.